# How do I return the value of a promise inside another promise?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am trying to return the value of a function of a promise inside a promise. Still pretty new to promises so any advise is much appreciated!

```
// card.service.ts

getCard(cardId: string): DocumentData {
    return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.currentUserId)
        .collection('cardsList').doc(cardId)
        .get()
        .then((docSnapShot) => {
            console.log((docSnapShot));
            return docSnapShot.data();
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
  }

addCardToWallet(userId: string, cardId: string, dataObject: DocumentData) {
      return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(userId)
          .collection('walletList')
          .doc(cardId)
          .set(
              dataObject
          );
  }

// scanner.component.ts
scanCode() {
   this.barcodeScanner.scan(
          {
           showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
           showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
           prompt : 'Scan a Kardbox QR' // Android
          }
     ).then((barcodeData) => {
         this.cardService.getCard(barcodeData.text)
             .then((data) => {
               // I want to add this to the database first

               this.cardService.addCardToWallet(this.currentUserId, barcodeData.text, data);

              // After adding values to database, navigate to other page

              this.router.navigate(['/home/wallet']);
        });
     });
 }
```

The output that I'm getting is the value of barcodeData and I have no idea why it's doing that.

Comment: What do you mean by _The output that I'm getting_? That output is in the method that calls the `scanCode()` method?

Comment: Yep you are right!

Comment: And what result do you want to return from `scanCode()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try async await, replace:

```
this.barcodeScanner.scan(
        {
          showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
          showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
          prompt : 'Scan a Kardbox QR' // Android
        }
    ).then((barcodeData) => {
        this.cardService.getCard(barcodeData.text)
            .then((data) => {
              // I want to add this to the database first
          this.cardService.addCardToWallet(this.currentUserId, barcodeData.text, data);

          // After adding values to database, navigate to other page

          this.router.navigate(['/home/wallet']);
    });
});
```

with:

```
const barcodeData = await this.barcodeScanner.scan(
  {
    showFlipCameraButton : true, // iOS and Android
    showTorchButton : true, // iOS and Android
    prompt : 'Scan a Kardbox QR' // Android
  },
);
const data = await this.cardService.getCard(barcodeData.text);

this.cardService.addCardToWallet(this.currentUserId, barcodeData.text, data);
this.router.navigate(['/home/wallet']);
```

And don't forget to add async before scancode() method.

Comment: Hi Msu Arven. Thank you for answering. I tested your solution however, unfortunately, it didn't work. Nothing was added to the database nor am i redirected to another page.

Comment: Add try catch and console log the error to see what is the problem

Comment: It's saying that the 'data' in this.cardService.getCard promise is undefined

Comment: Hmm, if You are initializing your const in try catch block then the const cannot be used outside this try catch scope, so put addCardToWallet and navigate methods in the try catch

Answer (score 0):

You should return a promise in your getCard(cardId: string) function

```
getCard(cardId: string): Promise<DataType or any> {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve,reject) => { 
         firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(this.currentUserId)
        .collection('cardsList').doc(cardId)
        .get()
        .then((docSnapShot) => {
            console.log((docSnapShot));
            resolve(docSnapShot.data());
        },
        (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

If you want to navigate after the data is added into the database you should put the router.navigate into the callback of addCardToWallet Method

```
this.cardService.addCardToWallet(this.currentUserId, barcodeData.text,data).then(res => {
      router.navigate(/somwhere)
});
```

Comment: Hi Ranika, thanks so much for answering. Unfortunately, I am also getting the same error as with the other solutions provided down below

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help. Please tell me if it doesn't.

```js
scanCode( ) {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan({
        showFlipCameraButton: true,
        showTorchButton: true,
        prompt: 'Scan a Kardbox QR'
    })
    .then( ( barcodeData ) => {
        this.cardService.getCard( barcodeData.text )
            .then( ( data ) => {
               // addCardToWallet returns a promise, right? Wait for it to return
               this.cardService.addCardToWallet( this.currentUserId, barcodeData.text, data )
                   .then( ( ) => {
                       // And after the card is added, tell the router to navigate
                       this.router.navigate([ '/home/wallet' ]);
                   })
            });
     })
     // Just in case, I recommend you to catch any error that might arise in the promise chain
     .catch( ( error ) => {
         console.error( 'Oops, something failed: "' + error + '"' );
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering Pato. The error is saying that the 'data' in this.cardService.getCard promise is undefined. Could you enlighten me on that?